# is_max = s == s.max() | How should I read this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

While studying [Pandas Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html), I got to the following:

```
def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_max]
```

How should I read `is_max = s == s.max()`?

Comment: `s == s.max()` is an expression, the result of which is assigned to `is_max`. On most objects, `==` produces a boolean value (`False` or `True`). If `s` is a series, then you'll get a series with boolean values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s == s.max()` will evaluate to a boolean (due to the `==` in between the variables). The next step is storing that value in `is_max`.

Comment: This is wrong. `s == s.max()` does not evaluate to a bool, `==` does not imply this

Answer (score 3):

In pandas `s` is very often `Series` (column in `DataFrame`).

So you compare all values in `Series` with `max` value of `Series` and get boolean mask. Output is in `is_max`. And then set style `'background-color: yellow'` only to cell of table where is `True` value - where is max value.

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

is_max = s == s.max()
print (is_max)
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

`is_max = s == s.max()`

is evaluated as

`is_max = (s == s.max())`

The bit in parentheses is evaluated first, and that is either `True` or `False`. The result is assigned to `is_max`.

Comment: In Python `==` equality testing can be overloaded. It doesn't necessarily produce a boolean. In Pandas, `Series` override this and produce a new series with boolean values. So `Series([1, 2, 4, 8]) == Series([1, 2, 4, 8]).max()` produces `Series([1, 2, 4, 8]) == 8` produces `Series([False, False, False, True])`.

Comment: There are many more languages where assignment is not an operator; making assignment an operator is actually an exception, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

> is_max is EQUAL TO comparison of s and s_max

Answer (score 0):

According to the document, [Evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order):

> Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is
>   evaluated before the left-hand side.

This is quite reasonable, for you have to know the value of an expression before assigning it to a variable.

So Python first evaluates `s.max()`, followed by checking if the calculated value is equal to `s`, resulting in a boolean result, and then assign this boolean to a variable called `is_max`.

See also: [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)